# Aeron Messaging - Shutting down subscribed app caused other subscribed apps on the same server to stall

Tags: aeron

We have an application on Server 1 publishing data.

Multiple applications (App A, B, C, D ,E for example) on Server 2 are subscribed and receiving this data. We need to upgrade one of the applications and so shutdown App E for example. This gracefully shuts down, closing the Subscription.

Other apps on other servers are unaffected.

The other existing running applications seem to stall and recover during the shutdown. Aeron Stat shows flow control over runs. I couldn't find any good documentation explaining for the over runs mean and how to rectify/tune out the issue.

Can anyone explain and point to where to fix, tune, or alleviate the stalls in existing running apps on the same channel?

Ensured closing and graceful shutdown of the application. Checked aeron stat and saw over runs (not sure what this EXACTLY means)

Comment: What Aeron version and strategy for flow control is configured?

Comment: 1.38.0 I think. No flow control specified so the default settings.

Comment: confirmed we are using aeron 1.38.1.
We are CPU bound - so have been running on a SHARED threading for the media driver, pinned to a core. We have tried SHARED_NETWORK with pinning of the network thread (and the conductor left to the shared cores on the server). We then tried pinning the conductor thread on SHARED_NETWORK but have the same results when the producers is busy.

Comment: We have tried DEDICATED with cpu pinning on each media driver thread and still have the problem. We don't see back pressure or failed offer() on the producer which is on a different server. Other consumers on other servers do not 'stall' either. Only consumers on the server with the 'restarted' consumer shows a stall. The AeronStat shows 'Flow control over run' increasing and NAKs Sent increasing by a count of 1.

Comment: I would highly recommend upgrading to 1.41.2 and retesting.  There were some fixes around flow control that went in around 1.39.0.

Comment: Have upgraded to 1.41.2. The stalling still happens on subscribers.  

The AeronStat shows zero flow control values now. We also had loss stat with the upgrade and can see zero lost as well from loss stat.

We have a simple command line subscriber, and this just dumps out all messages received. We can see the stall happen now - the stdout dump pauses momentarily and then resumes.

Is a theory that the restart of the app (unsubscribe and startup/subscribe) causes the media driver to pause as it cleans up / sets up internal buffers or other CNC related activity causing a stall plausible?

Comment: I'm reproducing the same problem with 1.41.2. The producer is back pressured at the moment of killing of the consumer process on ~5 seconds by default. I was able to decrease a period of the back pressured state by decreasing `publicationConnectionTimeoutNs` property of the media driver on the producer side. But when I set it less than a second the consumer cannot connect successfully when it is not warmed by JIT compiler (I mean cold start of JVM).

Comment: Just re-read and like to clarify. The stalling is the media driver not notifying consumers of messages (the apps that 'stall' are still polling and not paused) so it seems there is a stall/pause of incoming messages in the consuming apps. Using some of the linux tools suggested int he aeron cook book, the server is not strained on CPU, or disk IO.

Comment: You best best is to provide a runnable test that illustrates the problem and post it as an issue on Github.

Comment: RESOLVED. When trying to create simple apps to highlight issue, we found that the issue. Spring Boot is used and startup/shutdown lifecycle we had too long a time between subscribing and kicking off the dispatch thread, thus causing the term buffers to fill, causing flow control to kick in and thus causing the stalling. We fixed the startup and shutdown sequence and we no longer see any stalls from flow control working as expected.